# npm folder is empty while installing angular4

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to install angular4 so I installed Node v8.11.3, their version of npm is 5.5.1. I typed `npm install –g @angular/cli`, when trying ng, an error says ng is not recognized as an internal command. I see the folder C:\Users\user-\AppData it seems empty.

How can I solve this issue in order to install angular 4 environment correctly?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511183/ng-command-not-found

Answer (score -1):

**ng is not recognized as an internal command** error means **your node and npm are not installed correctly**.

Try reinstall node and npm.

Comment: Why? You can have node and npm, and even the project installed correctly, and still have ng not recognized.