# ng: command not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to run `ng build` in my project folder, but I get the following response:

> bash: ng: command not found

What am I missing? Does it have to do with admin privileges, my path/profile, or something I need to install globally?

This is my **`package.json`**:

```
{
"name": "meanauthapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "MEAN stack authentication app",
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node app"
},
"dependencies": {
"express": "4.16.2",
"mongoose": "4.13.6",
"bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
"cors": "2.8.4",
"jsonwebtoken": "8.1.0",
"body-parser": "1.18.2",
"passport": "0.4.0",
"passport-jwt": "3.0.1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In case others come here with this issue as I have, here is how I solved it system-wide on MacOS. Hope this helps.

Verify node is installed:

```
$ node -v
v11.2.0
```

Verify npm is installed:

```
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

Verify your npm global install file path is configured (known as [prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#prefix-configuration)). Mine is under ~/.npm-packages:

```
$ npm config ls -l | grep prefix
prefix = "/Users/christiangroleau/.npm-packages"
```

If not, you can place it into your ~/.npmrc file:

```
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
```

Verify that your prefix path is listed in your system PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/christiangroleau/.npm-packages/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If not, invoke the following:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
```

Finally, you can reinstall angular-cli (in my case I needed to install it globally):

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Verify installation:

```
$ ng -v
```

Answer (score 6):

try to uninstall and clean the cache.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: The package name is `@angular/cli`

Answer (score 6):

`npm` doesn't recognize `ng` command.

Try this command:

`npm link @angular/cli`

to link `npm` and `angular-cli`.

Comment: This was very useful for my particular issue.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
node_modules/.bin/ng build
```

Or better, add a blank `"ng": "ng"`line into your `scripts` key in package.json and run this:

```
`npm run ng build`
```

You could also add this to your path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:./node_modules/bin
```

Which would let you run any binary in any npm project you might have.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io) globally.
Run `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: I already have the Angular CLI installed globally and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @chody then this is not Angular CLI related. It seems like it is a general problem that you can't install global NPM packages. Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found

Comment: @chody can you please make sure angular cli is installed using `npm list -g --depth 0`, i loose my global installed packages Everytime I update node.

Comment: @sn42 I did that and it returned a lot of errors. What should I do to remedy this?

Comment: npm ERR! error in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarnpkg/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data: E
NOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarnpkg/node_modules/request/nod
e_modules/form-data/package.json'
npm ERR! invalid: form-data /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarnpkg/node_modules/request/node_modules/fo
rm-data
npm ERR! error in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/combined-stream: ENOENT: no such file
or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/combined-stream/package.json'

Answer (score 2):

For windows user: Just go to your windows environment setting and set user path as C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the dependencies locally and need to refer those packages instead of global. use `npx` before the the command eg: `npx ng build` refers to the locally installed package. `ng build` refers to the global package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but I am running Windows 10 and none of answers worked for me. These were the steps I took to get it resolved:

**Verify Angular is installed** by running the following command in Git BASH:

```
npm run ng -v
```

**Install Angular** if it is not already installed by running the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**Get the npm PATH** by running the following command:

```
npm config get prefix
```

**Open up advanced system settings** by either using the shortcut windows+pause (aka break) and clicking on *Advanced System Settings* or by using Cortana to search for the phrase *System Environment Variables*

**Click on Environment Variables** to bring up the environment variables dialog.

**Select the row** for the user variable *Path* and click on Edit

**Click on New** and enter the path returned from earlier. Then click on OK and OK again to close out of the Environment Variables dialog.

**Restart Git BASH** and test that it working by running the command:

```
ng -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to other answers: [This npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10004) might be related to your problem, your npm installation might be outdated.

First of check whether you use a recent version of node. Then update npm with `npm i -g npm` as the issue suggests (near bottom). Then if `ng` is still not found follow the [update instructions of @angular/cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/README.md#updating-angular-cli):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
# if npm version is < 5 then use 'npm cache clean'
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a pain to figure out, so here is my solution

```
1. npm install -g @angular/cli 
2. Make sure the ng path is correct
    * cd ~/npm-global/bin
    * ls and make sure ng exists here!
3. create .bashrc or .bash_profile or .bash_everything file on your home directory with:
    * touch ~/.bash_profile 
open this file with text editor or Sublime or vi or etc.
    * open -e .bash_profile 
4. Add ng as alias
    * writing this:
   alias ng="~/npm-global/bin/ng"  or   alias ng="MyFullPAThere/npm-global/bin/ng"
    * save file and close text editor. 
5. Temporarily Update . bash_profile reference Your terminal wont take bash updates until a restart but the following command will let you use the updates during the terminal session:
    * source ~/.bash_profile
6. Check that ng works
    * ng --version
```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have just copied a whole repository (including its `node_modules`) from a Windows machine to a Linux machine, and running `npx ng XXX` failed with the following error:

```
npx: installed 1 in 1.677s
command not found: ng
```

The main issue was, of course, line breaks. Using the `dos2unix` package, I was able to overcome it:

```
sudo apt install -y dos2unix
dos2unix node_modules/.bin/ng
chmod +x node_modules/.bin/ng
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac and using nvm then just alias you nvm dir node versions
like this

```
alias ng=/Users/your-user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```