# error in Angular ng command: opens with and gives a script page named ng :#!/usr/bin/env node 'use strict';

Tags: angular

I installed Angular and when I write a ng command I get this screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOxCO.png)

If I choose Google Chrome I get a script page

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

// Provide a title to the process in `ps`.
// Due to an obscure Mac bug, do not start this title with any symbol.
try {
  process.title = 'ng ' + Array.from(process.argv).slice(2).join(' ');
} catch(_) {
  // If an error happened above, use the most basic title.
  process.title = 'ng';
}

// Some older versions of Node do not support let or const.
var version = process.version.substr(1).split('.');
if (Number(version[0]) < 10 || (Number(version[0]) === 10 && Number(version[1]) < 9)) {
  process.stderr.write(
    'You are running version ' + process.version + ' of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.\n' +
    'The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.\n\n' +
    'Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.\n'
  );

  process.exit(3);
}

require('../lib/init');
```

Anyone please know about possible solutions?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511183/ng-command-not-found

Comment: No, I tried everything from there and the problem was repeated

Comment: Ok maybe 1) Delete you node modules folder.  2) ng update will give you the latest angular package which is now at 9.1.  Note I have had to more than once run ng update just to get the CLI running.  Then, I've had to separately use npm install to sync up both global and local versions of Angular...  I almost always see dependency warnings but mostly ignore them.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I used powershell (by the command line it didn't work) and reinstalled nodejs in a different version than the one I had, and it worked